# problem with extensions on mercurial

Tags: mercurial

i have this in my .hgrc but the extensions are not working

any idea why? im on a mac.

perhaps i could point it to their path? but I can't see to find anywhere where that would be.

thank you

.hgrc

```
[extensions]
fetch=
hgext.extdiff =
```

Comment: Are other items in this `.hgrc` taking effect?  It's easy to think a `.hgrc` is being consulted when really it's in the wrong path or permissions.  What does `hg help extensions` show?

Comment: yes.. the merge = kdiff3 seems to be working fine. but no ui pops up as i would like.. so other things are taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configured extdiff, so it won't know what to do. and you need to specify `hgext.fetch =` instead of just `fetch =`

Comment: Just `fetch =` is fine in any mercurial install that's not two years old.